# Word Crawler script not fetching the target words - Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I am a newbie to programming. Learning from Udacity. In unit 2, I studied the following code to fetch links from a particular url:

```
import urllib2
def get_page(url):
    return urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

def get_next_target(page):
    start_link = page.find('<a href=')
    if start_link == -1:
        return None, 0
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
    end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote + 1)
    url = page[start_quote + 1:end_quote]
    return url, end_quote

def print_all_links(page):
    while True:
        url, endpos = get_next_target(page)
        if url:
            print url
            page = page[endpos:]
        else:
            break

print_all_links(get_page('http://en.wikipedia.org'))
```

It worked perfectly. Today I wanted to modify this code so the script could crawl for a particular word in a webpage rather than URLs. Here is what I came up with:

```
import urllib2

def get_web(url):
    return urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

def get_links_from(page):
    start_at = page.find('america')
    if start_at == -1:
        return None, 0
    start_word = page.find('a', start_at)
    end_word = page.find('a', start_word + 1)
    word = page[start_word + 1:end_word]
    return word, end_word

def print_words_from(page):
    while True:
        word, endlet = get_links_from(page)
        if word:
            print word
            page = page[endlet:]
        else:
            break

print_words_from(get_web('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America'))
```

When I run the above, I get no errors, but nothing prints out either. So I added the print keyword -

```
print print_words_from(get_web('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America'))
```

When I run, I get None as result. I am unable to understand where am I going wrong. My code probably is messed up, but because there is no error coming up, I am unable to figure out where it is messed up.

Seeking help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand this as you are trying to get it to print the word America for every instance of the word on the Wikipedia page.

You are searching for "america" but the word is written "America". "a" is not equal to "A" which is causing you to find no results.

Also, start_word is searing for 'a', so I adjusted that to search for 'A' instead.

At this point, it was printing 'meric' over and over. I edited your 'word' to begin at 'start_word' rather than 'start_word + 1'. I also adjusted your 'end_word' to be 'end_word+1' so that it prints that last letter.

It is now working on my machine. Let me know if you need any clarification.

```
def get_web(url):
    return urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

def get_links_from(page):
    start_at = page.find('America')
    if start_at == -1:
        return None, 0

    start_word = page.find('A', start_at)
    end_word = page.find('a', start_word + 1)
    word = page[start_word:end_word+1]
    return word, end_word

def print_words_from(page):
    while True:
        word, endlet = get_links_from(page)
        if word:
            print word
            page = page[endlet:]
        else:
            break

print_words_from(get_web('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working perfectly. Plus, I understood where I went wrong. Thanks a ton!